# Team Foundation Server and MbUnit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, mbunit

I'm really new to TFS Server and MbUnit.

What steps do you need to do to make the builds on TFS run your MbUnit tests?

Comment: ... I'd be googling <code>NUnit MBUnit +"Team Build"</code> and seeing what that turns up.

Comment: Good call. I didn't know the builder was called "Team Build". Hows that for newb to TFS.

Comment: I'll see how far this gets me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154411/how-do-i-get-team-build-to-run-mbunit-tests

Answer (score 0):

You need either a custom build task or to simply execute the MbUnit executable passing in the appropriate arguments.

The steps taken in this nUnit example apply to an MbUnit implementation:
[NUnit Example](http://morten.lyhr.dk/2008/05/using-nunit-and-ncover-with-tfs-build.html)